# How to solve this complicated integration?

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, density-function

The PDF  of random variable $h$ is $$f_h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$$
I want to integrate PDF $f_\rho(x)$ i.e., $$\int_0^{h}f_\rho(x)\ dx$$
where $$f_\rho(x)=\frac{f_h(\sqrt{x/\rho_t})}{\sqrt{\rho_tx}}$$
I know the final answer includes error function. But having difficulty in reaching to final step. Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$f_h=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma ^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\qquad \text{and}\qquad f_\rho=\frac{f_h\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{\rho }}\right)}{\sqrt{\rho  x}}$$ then
$$f_\rho=\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2 \rho  \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi \rho \sigma ^2} \sqrt{ 
   x}}$$ Let
$$t^2=\frac{x}{2 \rho  \sigma ^2}\implies x=2 \rho  \sigma ^2 t^2\implies dx=4 \rho  \sigma ^2 t\, dt$$

$$\int f_\rho \,dx=\frac{2 }{\sqrt{\pi }}\int e^{-t^2}\,dt$$

Comment: Ok....i also solved it and achieved the required answer.....